# Extract specific string from variable

Tags: sql-server

I have a Variable that contains dynamic string. I want to get the word that is equal to `COATitle` only.

```
DECLARE @String Varchar(250)
 SET @String = 'COATitle = ''Hello'' AND Date = ''2018-10-09'' AND Name = ''Warner Bros'''

 SELECT @String AS String
```

This string is being provided from front end so user can enter in different order as well. For example

```
SET @String = 'Date = ''2018-10-09'' AND COATitle = ''Hello Tonia'' AND Name = ''Warner Bros'''
SET @String = 'COATitle = ''Hello'' AND Name = ''Warner Bros'' Date = ''2018-10-09'' AND '
SET @String = 'COATitle = ''Hello World'' AND Date = ''2018-10-09'' AND Name = ''Warner Bros'''
SET @String = 'COATitle = ''Piece of Cake'' AND Date = ''2018-10-09'' AND Name = ''Tim Martin'''
```

Expected output for above mentioned Strings are:

```
1: Hello Tonia
2: Hello
3: Hello World
4: Piece of Cake
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here is to just use base string functions in SQL Server.  We can take a substring of the input, using the starting point as the text which immediately follows `COATitle = '`, continuing until just before the very next closing single quote.

```
SELECT
    word,
    SUBSTRING(word,
              CHARINDEX('COATitle = ''', word) + 12,
              CHARINDEX('''', word, CHARINDEX('COATitle = ''', word) + 12) -
                  CHARINDEX('COATitle = ''', word) - 12) AS target
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo